# Deserialize a .json string returns: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to read a .json response. I have pasted the response here:
https://pastebin.com/0Zgg39si

Then I use the code below. When I run the code, I get the below error for:

***"var deserializedTickers"***

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

The code is the below. I am not sure what is causing this?

```js
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

        public void test()
        {
            //responseBody holds the .json response
            String responseBody = "";

            var deserializedTickers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TickersRoot>(responseBody);

            foreach (var ticker in deserializedTickers.Tickers)
            {
                var symbol2 = ticker.Value.Symbol;
            }
        }
        public class TickersRoot { public Dictionary<string, Ticker> Tickers { get; set; } }
        public class Ticker
        {
            public string Symbol { get; set; }
            public long Timestamp { get; set; }
            public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
            public double High { get; set; }
            public double Low { get; set; }
            public double Bid { get; set; }
            public double Ask { get; set; }
            public double Vwap { get; set; }
            public double Open { get; set; }
            public double Close { get; set; }
            public double Last { get; set; }
            public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
            public double QuoteVolume { get; set; }
            public Info Info { get; set; }
        }

        public class Info
        {
            public List<string> a { get; set; }
            public List<string> b { get; set; }
            public List<string> c { get; set; }
            public List<string> v { get; set; }
            public List<string> p { get; set; }
            public List<int> t { get; set; }
            public List<string> l { get; set; }
            public List<string> h { get; set; }
            public string o { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: There are two problems. The main one -- your `Info` class doesn't match the data. it has lists, but the source JSON has scalars. And the property names are different: there are no "buy", "sell", etc. Second (minor) problem with the data itself. inside `Info` class all data seems to be float, but only "open" is a number, everything else is marked as string.

Comment: And some property mismatch in the `Ticker` class as well. Plus you may need to mark some properties nullable or non-compulsory.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the response, your Info class should be something like this (set the datatype to match your needs):

```
public class Info
{
    public string Buy { get; set; }
    public string Sell { get; set; }
    public string Open { get; set; }
    public string Low { get; set; }
    public string High { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string Vol { get; set; }
}
```

as you don't have a property called "Tickers" on the json body, call the JsonConver.DeserializeObject method like this:

```
var deserializedTickers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Ticker>>(responseBody);
```

then you can iterate the result as:

```
foreach (var ticker in deserializedTickers)
{
    var symbol2 = ticker.Value.Symbol;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, then I understand. I am bit bad when it comes to JSON but I learn more each time now. Then I see, I don't have a property called "Tickers" that made good sense then. And how you did deserialize it directly using "Ticker".

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when one of my [Serializable] objects only had 1 constructor with a required arg. When de-serializing, the newtonsoft.json package could not create the entity from the data, since it had a required param in its constructor.

I solved it by removing the constructor and remembering to call a helper function when instantiating objects that are not loaded from a file/json.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Just made an empty constructor with no parameter. How stupid, took me two hours to figure this out.

Comment: Yay, happy I could help!

Comment: Although I don't fully understand why, it seems like adding a default parameterless constructor would have fixed this without requiring the need to remove your constructor with params.

Comment: It is because there are no parameters to pass into it when it is being instantiated automatically. I could have a parameter-less constructor but there would have been nothing for it to do, so I just removed it. All I wanted my constructor to do was to save the parameter to an instance variable, so I used a helper after it was instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the root json object to have a property named "tickers" that encapsulates the dictionary

```
{
    "tickers":{
        "BTC/AUD": {
            ...
        },
        ...
     }
}
```

Or deserialize the original json directly into a dictionary

```cs
var deserializedTickers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Ticker>>(responseBody);
```

You should also change the Info class to match the json schema

Comment: Thank you for your help! That was a great help!